# DOM manipulation slow in Chrome (hiding / showing elements)

Tags: javascript, google-chrome, dom, pagination

I've put together a small test at http://jsfiddle.net/Hwqb3/3/ this morning. This is on the back of a larger project with pagination. I have tried this with native JS and jQuery. The test uses jQuery.

A quick search on SO says that Chrome handles things poorly if background-size is set, but this is not the case here. No trace of background-size in the source, and inspecting elements shows no background-size being set / inherited.

Ignore the initial page load while 5,000 elements are added to the list. It is only a few seconds, but it just so there are some elements to test with.

In Firefox 18.0.1, the moving between pages is almost instant and in IE9 there is maybe a 0.1s delay between mouse click and the paged results refreshing; However, in Chrome (24.0.1312.57 m) the delay is a noticeable 1-2 seconds.

I spent the majority of my night last night pouring over my code to see if I can find the cause before writing this test. This is bare bones and still has the issue.

I can only assume that Chrome is handling the element.style.display=''; poorly. Without that (even looping through the 5,000 elements to display='none') the thing is snappy.

Any ideas? Client wants pagination on a result set of around 4,000 - 7,500, but doesn't want page reloads and doesn't understand that they should apply filters to whittle that list down to <100, as no one is ever going to page through 200 - 375 pages looking for something specific.

Last resort is AJAX calls, which may be slightly quicker on Chrome. Untested yet though.

Thanks in advance.

Code from jsfiddle, excluding the jQuery CDN link

HTML:

```
<a href="javascript:jump('first');">First</a>
<a href="javascript:jump('-1');">Previous</a>

<a href="javascript:jump('+1');">Next</a>
<a href="javascript:jump('last');">Last</a>
<br>
<ul id='list'>
</ul>
```

JS:

```
window.onload=function() { 
    window.list=$('#list'), window.max=20, window.page=0, window.pages=0, window.elements;

    var i=0;
    while(i<5000) {   
        i++;
        list.append("<li>"+i+"</li>");
    }

    jump('first');
};

function jump(operation) {

    window.elements=list.find('li');
    window.pages=Math.ceil(window.elements.length/window.max);

    if(operation=='first') {
        window.page=0;
    }
    else if(operation=='last') {
        window.page=(window.pages-1);
    }
    else if(operation=='+1') {
        window.page=(window.page+1);
        if(window.page>=window.pages) {
            window.page=(window.pages-1);
        }
    }
    else if(operation=='-1') {
        window.page=(window.page-1);
        if(window.page<0) {
            window.page=0;
        }
    }

    var showing=0, total=0;

    window.elements.each(function() {
        var show=false, self=$(this);

        if(showing<window.max) {
            if(total>=(window.page*window.max) && total<((window.page*window.max)+window.max)) {
                self[0].style.display='';
                showing++;
                show=true;
            }
        }

        if(!show) {
            self[0].style.display='none';
        }
        total++;
    });


}
```

Comment: Bad way to use `javascript:...` in `href` of tag `a`

Comment: This was a 20 minute test-case code, not real/production code, to highlight what the issue was. Otherwise I'd have included a DOCTYPE et al.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

check this

```
window.onload = function() { 
    window.list = $('#list'), 
    window.max = 20, 
    window.page = 0, 
    window.pages = 0, 
    window.elements;

    var i = 0;
    var html = '';
    while(i < 5000) { 
        i++
        html += '<li>' + i + '</li>';
    }    
    list.append(html);

    window.elements = list.find('li');
    window.pages = Math.ceil(window.elements.length/window.max);    

    jump('first');
};



function jump(operation) {

    if (operation == 'first') 
        window.page = 0;
    else if (operation == 'last') 
        window.page = window.pages - 1;
    else if (operation == '+1') 
        (window.page + 1 >= window.pages) ? window.page = window.pages - 1 : window.page++ ;
    else if (operation == '-1') 
        (window.page - 1 < 0) ? window.page = 0 : window.page--;

    var index = page * window.max;
    window.elements.hide().slice(index, index + window.max).show();
}
```

http://jsfiddle.net/Hwqb3/16/

Comment: Instead of using a class for every page, you could combine 2 `:nth-child()` selector: `li:nth-child(n+5):nth-child(-n+10)` http://jsfiddle.net/Hwqb3/6/ Using `:nth-child()` shouldn't prevent jQuery from using browsers' `querySelectorAll()` function, so it also should be fast enough.

Comment: Well, `:nth-child():nth-child()` is slow as hell at the end of the list: http://jsfiddle.net/Hwqb3/8/

Comment: other problem, is then you add new elements or delete, nth-child recalculates.. this may be slow too on long list

Comment: While I know I only asked the question specific to pagination, the paged results (because of the no-refresh rule) are filterable also using javascript, so the results that are paged change (I am, therefore, finding elements by something like `$('#list > li.match')`.

I could re-calculate the pages and shuffle elements around in pages after each filter, I guess, which I would need to do if I went for the class route also; However, the class route potentially won't (shouldn't) affect DOM if the classes are empty.

I'll take a look at that once I get home. Thanks.

Comment: you want another filter to add to page filter and preserve the original pagination?

Comment: So this is interesting.

If the elements are output directly to the browser from PHP/HTML, Chrome still struggles. If the elements are generated after the page has loaded via JS, Chrome is considerably quicker (~0.1s vs ~10 - 40+s).

On the 'static' elements, the further into the pages you get (there are 200 something, so choose around 180) the quicker it is. I can only assume Chrome, for some reason, wants to recalculate the position of all the hidden elements that come after the 'paged' results. Maybe.

Thanks for your help.

Updated fiddle to demonstrate: http://jsfiddle.net/Aeisor/Hwqb3/19

Comment: glad to be helpful, enjoy!